# Cannot build composer on OSX Mojave 10.14.6 (18G1012)

Tags: botframework

I am trying to run composer for the first time, but it is failing with an error. I am installing NPM, Node, and Yarn via homebrew. Is there anything else I am missing to install?

This is the output log, any ideas?

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   '/usr/local/Cellar/node/12.12.0/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/usr/local/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'runtime'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.11.3
3 info using node@v12.12.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'preruntime', 'runtime', 'postruntime' ]
5 info lifecycle @bfc/root@~preruntime: @bfc/root@
6 info lifecycle @bfc/root@~runtime: @bfc/root@
7 warn lifecycle The node binary used for scripts is /var/folders/3y/_gn_bnhx1cl32ncq_fgwjg380000gp/T/yarn--1572912515208-0.5343445208387498/node but npm is using /usr/local/Cellar/node/12.12.0/bin/node itself. Use the `--scripts-prepend-node-path` option to include the path for the node binary npm was executed with.
8 verbose lifecycle @bfc/root@~runtime: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
9 verbose lifecycle @bfc/root@~runtime: PATH: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/Users/pswimm/Documents/code/docs/convo/BotFramework-Composer/Composer/node_modules/.bin:/var/folders/3y/_gn_bnhx1cl32ncq_fgwjg380000gp/T/yarn--1572912515208-0.5343445208387498:/Users/pswimm/Documents/code/docs/convo/BotFramework-Composer/Composer/node_modules/.bin:/Users/pswimm/.config/yarn/link/node_modules/.bin:/Users/pswimm/Documents/code/docs/convo/BotFramework-Composer/Composer/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/Cellar/node/12.12.0/libexec/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/node-gyp-bin:/usr/local/Cellar/node/12.12.0/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/node-gyp-bin:/usr/local/Cellar/node/12.12.0/bin/node_modules/npm/bin/node-gyp-bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
10 verbose lifecycle @bfc/root@~runtime: CWD: /Users/pswimm/Documents/code/docs/convo/BotFramework-Composer/Composer
11 silly lifecycle @bfc/root@~runtime: Args: [ '-c', 'cd ../BotProject/CSharp/ && dotnet build && dotnet run' ]
12 info lifecycle @bfc/root@~runtime: Failed to exec runtime script
13 verbose stack Error: @bfc/root@ runtime: `cd ../BotProject/CSharp/ && dotnet build && dotnet run`
13 verbose stack spawn ENOENT
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:48:18)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:210:5)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:283:5)
14 verbose pkgid @bfc/root@
15 verbose cwd /Users/pswimm/Documents/code/docs/convo/BotFramework-Composer/Composer
16 verbose Darwin 18.7.0
17 verbose argv "/usr/local/Cellar/node/12.12.0/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "runtime"
18 verbose node v12.12.0
19 verbose npm  v6.11.3
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error syscall spawn
22 error file sh
23 error errno ENOENT
24 error @bfc/root@ runtime: `cd ../BotProject/CSharp/ && dotnet build && dotnet run`
24 error spawn ENOENT
25 error Failed at the @bfc/root@ runtime script.
25 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
26 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: Can add the steps you are following and where you encounter the error? Can also add which version of npm, node, and yarn you are using? From the root of the Composer Directory, you should change directories into the Composer folder and run `yarn install`, `yarn build`, and `yarn start`.

Comment: Also do you have dotnet installed on your machine? It looks the error is thrown when Composer tries to run `dotnet build`.

Comment: I do, all just the default versions that come through homebrew install. Are there specific versions I should be using for each? I was in the private beta and had to manually install an old version of gulp-sass or something

Comment: Aha reinstalling dotnet did the trick, thanks for the tip!